# How to configure Firebase Hosting to serve my app from my custom domain with and without the "www" subdomain?

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I want my website to be accessible from: `www.myexamplewebsite.pt` AND `myexample.pt`. With and without the `www` part.

Right now only `www.myexamplewebsite.pt` is working.

When I try to access `myexamplewebsite.pt` (without `www`) this happens:

- 1. I get a Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead page
- 2. And even if I choose to proceed on the Warning page, I get a **page not found from Firebase** like this one:

[image]

---

- **Here is my current Hosting config for my Custom Domain:**

[image]

---

- **And here is a DNS CNAME record I have on my DNS provider.**

Note: Since I'm getting a page not found from Firebase (as mentioned above), I guess that there's nothing wrong with my DNS settings.

[image]

---

**QUESTION**

How can my web app be accessible from both URLs (with and without the `www`) ?

The only piece of Firebase Hosting doc that I found that mentions this, didn't help me very much:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#set-up

[image]

**UPDATE:** Here is my DNS config:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, creating the DNS A records for both the domains (i.e. `www.myexamplewebsite.pt` and `myexamplewebsite.pt` in your case) does the trick. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#go-live for the doc on DNS A records creation.

Comment: Hey, Renaud. I have very little knowledge of DNS configs, but doesn't the fact that I get a "Not found page" from Firebase when I hit `mywebsite.pt` prove that my DNS config is redirecting the request to the Firebase servers? From the Firebase Doc I linked on the question, it seems that something can be done on the Firebase side to handle that config. Also, my DNS provider just answered me that my config is correct for what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for your help. If I find any other solution, I'll post here.

Comment: Could you add to your question a print screen of your DNS A records?

Comment: I've added the records to the question. I also found a way to make it work and posted an answer. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working.

1 - I've added my 1st custom domain. I think I've entered it without the `www` (almost sure)

2 - Somehow, after it's been connected (detected the DNS records), it was displayed on Firebase Hosting with the `www` (it's the last one in the second picture below)

3 - Then I've added a new custom domain. Again, this time for sure I've entered it without `www` and marked to redirect to my domain with the `www`

**Result:** Not my app is accessible with and without the `www`

---

**DNS Config**

[image]

**Firebase Hosting Domains:**

[image]